# How to write a query for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How to write a query for PostgreSQL that will list the tables used by the selected materialized view ?
And explain how this query works.

```
CREATE TABLE films (
    id             integer PRIMARY KEY,
    title          varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    release_date   date,
    lenght         interval hour to minute,
    distributor_id integer 
);

CREATE TABLE distributors (
    id             integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name           varchar(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW films_ext AS
SELECT 
   f.id,
   f.title,
   f.release_date,
   f.lenght,
   d.name as distributor
from films f 
    INNER JOIN distributors d 
        ON f.distributor_id = d.id;
```

Comment: Looks like homework. What problem do you face?

Comment: Yes, I need create something like that and explain how this query works